# launching multiple applications using Parallel::ForkManager

Tags: perl, parallel-processing

I am using perl's `Parallel::ForkManager` to launch multiple applications in parallel. I have two subroutines, one for launching the application and other for performing data processing on the output files generated as a result of the application's complete run. 
In the first subroutine, I make a `system()` call to `cd` to the desired directory and launch the application there. I call the second subroutine inside the first subroutine after the `system()` call.

The problem is that after all the runs are launched, the program exits and the data processing that is done by the 2nd subroutine never gets completed, all I have are the output files of the application that appear after the runs are completed in the background.

Here is my code of what I am doing

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Parallel::ForkManager;
use Getopt::Long;

# Get input from the command line. Also get max_no_processes for Parallel::ForkManager
# Perform operations on the input file and seperate out data from them in form of arrays.   
# The arrays thus formed contain arguments for the application and path_to_directory where operation is to be performed

my $pm = new Parallel::ForkManager($max_no_processes);

for (my $i = 0; $i < $#input; $i++){  #----> @input is the array containing the input for  the application. using its length as max value.
    $pm->start and next;
    &subroutine1( $input[$i], $path_to_directory[$i] );
    $pm->finish;
}

$pm->wait_all_children;

sub subroutine1{
    my($input, $dir) = @_;

    system("cd dir && APPLICAION -$input");

    &subroutine2($dir);
}

sub subroutin2{
     my ($dir) = @_;

     # data processing
     # print to stdout and file
}
```

Comment: It would be good if you could post code that we can actually run to verify the problem. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org) for guidance.

Comment: Where do you define `$max_no_processes`?